# Simple socket program fails sporadically

Tags: c++, c, sockets

I've written a small socket program that connects 500 clients to a server all on `localhost` in very quick succession. I'm running macOS 10.12 with Xcode 8.0 and I'm noticing that this program fails about 50% of the time. The output shows the correct number of client connection attempt calls, but after that the connection never gets made. Like I said, sometimes it works just fine.

My expected output is that the output should contain 500 lines each of `CLIENT TRYCONNECT`, `CLIENT CONNECT`, and `SERVER ACCEPT`. I always get the correct number of `TRYCONNECT` messages, but often the other two fall significantly short of the expected 500 -- the program just locks waiting for the connections from the client that never arrive.

Any idea what could be going on here?

Here's the source (as simple as I could make it):

```
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <mutex>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <sys/fcntl.h>
#include <sys/poll.h>
#include <sys/select.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <thread>

const int PORT    = 1111;
const int CLIENTS = 500;

using namespace std;

mutex mtx;

#define thr throw runtime_error("error");

void server()
{
    int err;
    addrinfo hints    = {}, *res;
    hints.ai_family   = AF_INET6;
    hints.ai_flags    = AI_PASSIVE;
    hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;

    err = getaddrinfo(nullptr, to_string(PORT).c_str(), &hints, &res);
    if (err != 0) thr;

    int fd = socket(res->ai_family, res->ai_socktype, res->ai_protocol);
    if (fd == -1) thr;

    err = fcntl(fd, F_SETFL, O_NONBLOCK);
    if (err == -1) thr;

    socklen_t val;
    val = 0;
    err = setsockopt(fd, IPPROTO_IPV6, IPV6_V6ONLY, &val, sizeof val);
    val = 1;
    err = setsockopt(fd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, &val, sizeof val);
    val = 1;
    err = setsockopt(fd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_KEEPALIVE, &val, sizeof val);

    err = ::bind(fd, res->ai_addr, res->ai_addrlen);
    if (err == -1) thr;

    err = listen(fd, 0);
    if (err == -1) thr;

    freeaddrinfo(res);

    int connected = 0;

    for (;;) {
        sockaddr_storage client;
        socklen_t sz = sizeof client;
        int cfd = accept(fd, (sockaddr*)&client, &sz);
        if (cfd < 0) {
            if (errno == EAGAIN || errno == EWOULDBLOCK) {
                continue;
            } else {
                thr;
            }
        } else {
            lock_guard<mutex> lk(mtx);
            cout << "SERVER ACCEPT ON " << cfd << endl;
            if (++connected == CLIENTS) return;
        }
    }
}

void client()
{
    addrinfo hints    = {}, *res;
    hints.ai_family   = AF_UNSPEC;
    hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;
    int err;

    err = getaddrinfo("localhost", to_string(PORT).c_str(), &hints, &res);
    if (err == -1) thr;

    int fd = socket(res->ai_family, res->ai_socktype, res->ai_protocol);
    if (fd == -1) thr;

    err = fcntl(fd, F_SETFL, O_NONBLOCK);
    if (err == -1) thr;

    socklen_t val;
    val = 1;
    err = setsockopt(fd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_KEEPALIVE, &val, sizeof val);

    err = connect(fd, res->ai_addr, res->ai_addrlen);
    if (err == -1 && errno != EINPROGRESS) thr;

    freeaddrinfo(res);

    {
        lock_guard<mutex> lk(mtx);
        cout << "CLIENT TRYCONNECT ON " << fd << endl;
    }

    for (;;) {
        this_thread::sleep_for(chrono::milliseconds(100));

        pollfd ufds = { 0 };
        ufds.fd = fd;
        ufds.events = POLLOUT;
        poll(&ufds, 1, 0);

        if (!(ufds.revents & POLLOUT)) {
            continue;
        }

        int val;
        socklen_t val_sz = sizeof val;
        getsockopt(fd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_ERROR, &val, &val_sz);

        if (val < 0) {
            if (errno == EINPROGRESS) {
                continue;
            }
        }

        lock_guard<mutex> lk(mtx);
        cout << "CLIENT CONNECT ON " << fd << endl;
        return;
    }
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    thread t1(server);

    thread clients[CLIENTS];
    for (int i = 0; i < CLIENTS; ++i)
        clients[i] = thread(client);

    t1.join();
    for (int i = 0; i < CLIENTS; ++i)
        clients[i].join();
}
```

EDIT: Properly freeing address info in client

UPDATE: By running `lsof` on the process, I've found that several of the "missing" connections are marked as `CLOSED` instead of `ESTABLISHED`, so somehow they're getting shut down. I'd not yet sure what could trigger that, but I'm looking into it.

UPDATE: By adding a short (1 millisecond) sleep between starting up client connections the program runs flawlessly. It looks like perhaps a fault in the operating system implementation of sockets that prevents macOS from starting up too many connections simultaneously?

Comment: Any particular reason for the downvote?

Comment: C or C++? Surely you aren't writing both at the same time. I didn't downvote - but I am guessing this is why people have.

Comment: @RiccardoMutschlechner Ugh, people are still stuck on this? I'm using `iostreams` -- that's C++. I'm using C++11 threads and `chrono`. That's not C. Low-level socket programming? Although it's valid C++, I'd argue that it would look more familiar to C programmers. It follows C style and patterns. If I took out the C++ portions, I could easily post this sample with a C tag. Or I could keep it here with my small C++ additions. That's why I feel it's appropriate to tag it as both. In many ways I *am* writing both at the same time.

Comment: That's understandable. No idea what the issue is :(

Comment: Have you considered printing out something more useful than `"error"`?

Comment: @EJP None of those runtime errors are triggered. The code is there to show people that I'm actually checking them. Nothing returns an error, it's just that the connections never go through.

Comment: "*that prevents macOS from starting up too many connections simultaneously*" it's not the OS, but your code setting up the connections.

Comment: Are you sure with this `if (val < 0) {
            if (errno == EINPROGRESS) { ...`?

Comment: @alk I believe it's correct since I'm calling `connect()` on a non-blocking socket. It returns `EINPROGRESS` since it hasn't yet completed the handshake.

Comment: At least the use of `errno` is wrong, as it might be changed by many other functions. To have its value as set by `connect()` available later, store it to another variable the moment`connect()` returns and use this variable later.

Comment: @alk I'm not sure how I can do better than saying `int err = connect(...)`. As far as I understand it, this is the correct approach to error checking for sockets? How could I ever be guaranteed that the `errno` I'm examining is related to the previous call I've made in a multithreaded environment?

Comment: `errno` is really a macro for a function call. It isn't a variable and it doesn't suffer from thread-safety problems. I don't know what @alk is talking about here. The initial problem here is that you aren't reporting all errors, and you're only attempting to handle EINPROGRESS. You need to fix that and tell us what errors are reported.

Comment: @EJP I'm confused -- shouldn't my code throw an error on anything *except* `EINPROGRESS`? If `errno` is -1, the only thing it *won't* throw an error on is `EINPROGRESS`, which is what I believe I want.

`if (err == -1 && errno != EINPROGRESS) thr;`

Comment: @EJP I think there may be some validity to the thread safety idea though, no? I mean, if multiple threads are calling functions that set `errno` at the same time, isn't it possible than an error could be hidden because it gets set back to "ok" before I'm able to check that there was actually an error at some stage?

Comment: @EJP Upon further reading, I realized that `errno` is thread-safe (I guess it's thread local), so I'm back to having no idea why this fails.

Answer (score 0):

Your client has memory leaks.
Calls to `addrinfo` are dynamically allocated from`getaddrinfo`.
You need to call `freeaddrinfo` after their usage.

Failing to clean up `addrinfo` might be causing problems when trying to re-use the port number.

Comment: It's a good note, but doesn't solve the problem. I was correctly cleaning up on the server side, but not on the client side. I added a corresponding call to `freeaddrinfo` on the client side and the problem remains.

Comment: Memory leaks have nothing to do with port reuse, and there is no evidence that either of these is the problem.